# series involving q-pochhammer symbol

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have the following series:
$$
f(t,q)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (tq)^k (q;q)_k,
$$
where $(q;q)_k$ is the $q$-[pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), $0<q<1$. I suspect the series could be simplified, perhaps by identifying it with a special function of some kind, but I don't see how to do this, and would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
  -Alex

Answer (score 1):

Your series is equal to ${}_2\phi_{1}\big(\begin{smallmatrix}q,q \\0 \end{smallmatrix}\big|q;qt\big)$, where 
$$ {}_2\phi_{1}\big(\begin{smallmatrix}a,b \\c \end{smallmatrix}\big|q;z\big)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a;q)_n (b;q)_n}{(c;q)_n (q;q)_n} z^n $$ is the *basic hypergeometric series*. There is a vast amount of literature on these special functions; a detailed reference is Gasper & Rahman's *Basic hypergeometric series*. Maybe you will find some interesting property related to your work there.

Comment: Your post only introduces a notation for OP's functions, and then suggests that *maybe* an answer could be found somewhere in a book - but it's not guaranteed. This should have been a comment, at best.